# Полупрозрачные полосы над строками listview при наведении (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

я начал изучать wpf и делаю проект, что-то типа теста, и в конце вам выводит результат теста в listview. Все отображается корректно, но если навести курсор на строку, то над ней появляется полупрозрачная полоса. Подскажите, как от нее избавиться

```html
<ListView x:Name="ResultsList"  Grid.Column="1" FontSize="17" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCorrAnswered}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCorrAnswered}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="№" Width="30">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" FontSize="17" Text="{Binding Id}">
                                    <TextBox.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackGround}"/>
                                    </TextBox.Background>
                                </TextBox>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Вопрос" Width="815">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Width="815" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" FontSize="17" Text="{Binding Question}">
                                    <TextBox.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackGround}"/>
                                    </TextBox.Background>
                                </TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Ваш ответ" Width="120">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" Width="120" FontSize="17" Text="{Binding CheckedAnsw}">
                                    <TextBox.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackGround}"/>
                                    </TextBox.Background>
                                </TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Верный ответ" Width="130">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="White" Width="130" FontSize="17" Text="{Binding Corr_Answ}">

                                    <TextBox.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackGround}"/>
                                    </TextBox.Background>
                                </TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

вот сама программа(таблица результатов)

[image: вот сама программа(таблица результатов)]

Comment: Стандартно у ListViewItem есть некий эффект "блика", вот его вы и не убрали. Переопределите шаблон и будет вам счастье. Ну а вообще я не пойму для чего вы ставите везде `<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackGround}"/>` (это кстати он перекрывает этот эффект "блика" и из за этого вы видите его рывками)? Вот вы например установите ваш `BackGround` в `Transparent` и получите [красивый](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffoZE.png) вид с эффектом "блика".

Comment: извините, не могли бы вы добавить этот участок кода, а то я не пойму как установить BackGround в Transparent

Comment: Ну вы же его привязываете, делаете `{Binding BackGround}`, значит это свойство `BackGround` должно быть у вас там же, где например и `IsCorrAnswered` или `Question`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, понял)

Comment: Все работает, можете оформлять это как ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стандартно у ListViewItem есть некий эффект "блика", вот его вы и не убрали. Переопределите шаблон и будет вам счастье. Ну а вообще я не пойму для чего вы ставите везде `<SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackGround}"/>` (это кстати он перекрывает этот эффект "блика" и из за этого вы видите его рывками)? Вот вы например установите ваш `BackGround` в `Transparent` и получите [красивый вид](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffoZE.png) с эффектом "блика".